# Remove a Div class that inside a parent Div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div on top of a image. I want use jQuery click event to remove (or change the div class) the div on image click.

Div structure.

```
<div class="post">

<img class="thumb" src="MyImg.jpg">

<div class="show-div"></div>

</div>
```

I want to toggle class show-div to remove-div.

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".thumb").click( function(){

    $(this).parent().('.show-div').toggleClass('remove-div'); 
   });
});
```

I have made remove-div class to display none in the css style sheet. but this doesnt seems to work. Also i have tried

```
$(this).parent().find('.show-div').toggleClass('remove-div');
```

Please note that this is a PHP while loop and there will be more then one div at this page.

If someone can point me out the right way to do this it will be most appropriated.

Comment: The second attempt looks right, depending on your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".thumb").click( function(){
    $(this).parent().find('div.show-div').removeClass('show-div').addClass('remove-div'); 
   });
});
```

Comment: @zack but can you toggle it back...?

Comment: Your answer is ok but it won't allow the element to be toggled back. It's useful to explain the problem.

Comment: @NigelAngel i don't want to toggle back.

Comment: Then just use `.remove()` instead of adding a class.

Answer (score 2):

The code given works http://jsfiddle.net/4WDet

However, you're not removing `.show-div`, so if that is `display: block` AND your CSS rules are in this order that is your problem.

```
.remove-div{
    display:none;
}
.show-div{
    display:block;
}
```

In which case, switch your CSS styles around

```
.show-div{
    display:block;
}
.remove-div{
    display:none;
}
```

**or** toggle both classes

```
$(this).parent().find('.show-div').toggleClass('remove-div show-div');
```

But the problem then is that you won't find that div again, so you need to change the selector:

```
$(this).parent().find('.show-div, .remove-div').toggleClass('remove-div show-div');
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4WDet/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

.show-div is not a parent of .thumb, but a sibling. Have you tried?

```
$(this).siblings('.show-div').toggleClass('remove-div');
```

Note, that this will return an array if there are more than one .show-div sibling.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).siblings().toggle("slow");
```

try this